# can't use a UIKit code in Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, xcode, uikit, cocos2d-iphone

well I have created a game with UIKit and I have somme performance problems so I decided to use Cocos2D.I would like to use this code one cocos2D but I can't manage to do it :

```
- (CGPoint)randomPointSquare {
CGRect frame = [[self view] frame];

//CGFloat rand_x = ((float)arc4random() / (float)UINT_MAX) * (float)_window.frame.size.width;

NSInteger side = arc4random() / (UINT_MAX/4);
CGFloat offset = 0;

switch(side) {
    case 0: /* top */
        offset = ((float)arc4random() / (float)UINT_MAX) * (float)frame.size.width;
        return CGPointMake(offset, -10);

    case 1: /* bottom */
        offset = ((float)arc4random() / (float)UINT_MAX) * (float)frame.size.width;
        return CGPointMake(offset, frame.size.height-150);

    case 2: /* left */
        offset = ((float)arc4random() / (float)UINT_MAX) * (float)frame.size.height;
        return CGPointMake(-10, offset);

    default:
    case 3: /* right */
        offset = ((float)arc4random() / (float)UINT_MAX) * (float)frame.size.height;
        return CGPointMake(frame.size.width+200, offset);
}
}
-(void) createNewImage {

UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_03.png"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];
}
```

Can someone try to translate this code to use it in cocos2D.Thank you .Sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: It seems that you try to add an image with a random center point. In Cocos2D you should have a look at the CCSprite class an remember that coordinates in Cocos2D are not Upper Left Origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably be best off creating a new cocos2d project from the template and then inserting your game logic into the code as needed while translating the view components as needed.

For example, your UIImage would instead be a CCSprite.

But you might be better to encapsulate your movement code inside an object that contains a CCSprite so you can then just reuse that object.

I'd start by creating a new cocos2d project from the template and looking at the hello world example. Then start by adding a CCSprite to that and make it move around a bit. There's lots of tutorials out there - [This for example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial)